# Create horizontal line separating top and bottom part of element

Tags: html, css

What I would like to do is make a bordered element with a horizontal line inside which contains an image at the top and text at the bottom. I had no idea how to make a div with a border and a horizontal line separating it.

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Do what specifically? there's lots of stuff going on in that image

Comment: Please be more specific and show us your previous try

Comment: A border with horizontal line inside which contains image at the top and text at the bottom. I had no idea how to make a border with a line at the center of it.

Comment: @Paulie_D: The question "How do I make something look like this picture?" would be off topic like you say, but the question "How can I create a horizontal border separating two parts of a div?" would be on-topic so I've answered it as such.

Comment: Your div with border has some internal elements (e.g. heading etc.), right? You can always use the top or bottom (whichever you chose) border of one of that element as a separator line.

Answer (score 1):

What you've asked is how to create a horizontal border between two sections of a div, the easiest way I can think of is to just use an `<hr />` element. You could also of course do this by stacking two divs vertically, but I think this is simplest.

```css
.split-box {
  border: black 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.split-box hr {
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.split-text {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="split-box">
  <div class="split-text">
    Top part of box
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="split-text">
    Bottom part of box
  </div>
</div>
```

You can run the code snippet above to see this in action.

Comment: It's worked. Thanks for the big help.